# Woocommerce price wrong on cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I think my issue has to do with the cart page, but I can't seem to be able to fix it.
I have two books as products: one at 17.99 and the other one 12.95, however when I open the 12.95 book (product) and click "add to cart" the price on the cart reflects 17.99 NOT 12.95, even though the thumbnail and title are correct, 
I am using DIVI theme.

url: https://makelifeasuccess.com

PLEASE HELP!

[product page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO53h.jpg)

[cart page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZA4l.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Regards

Comment: Maybe you display price excluding tax in product page. Take a look to [WooCommerce documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-taxes-in-woocommerce/)

Comment: ZecKa, I tried removing taxable, and adding it back in, to each product, nothing works... however, I saw that on the category (product) category, the price is 17.99 for both books, I changed the category, and still the same problem ...